# Installing OpenJDK 8 on RHEL 7 fails

Tags: java, rhel

Running into an issue where a scripted install that used to work started failing with this error.

```
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
Requires: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64)
```

I'm guessing that it's a repo hiccup but wondering if there's a fix that I can roll out while we wait for the maintainers to get on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a recently introduced packaging bug:

- [java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64 requires pcsc-lite-devel which is in optional repo [rhel-7.6.z]](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1684403), with more discussion in the [parent bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1684077).

An erratum for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6 has been released to address the issue:

- [RHBA-2019:0452 java-1.8.0-openjdk bug fix update](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2019:0452)

You can also work around the problem by temporarily enabling the (nominally unsupported) `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` or `rhel-7-workstation-optional-rpms` channel (depending on the product variant).

Comment: I tried to enable either of the repositories listed in answer #2 and got errors saying neither repo existed (command: yum-config-manager --enablerepo=rhel-7-workstation-optional-rpms). I've also tried to download a more recent package, but there doesn't seem to be any that don't have this same error. Anyone successful at getting this issue resolved?